# Github organization member can't merge PR's even though he has write access

Tags: github

I have a protected github repository, where I want a user that was already allowed 'read' access to also be able to merge PR's, so I gave him the 'write' role. According to the [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-user-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/repository-roles-for-an-organization) that should be enough. Still he is not able to merge, and he sees a warning about not having write access. Am I missing something?

Comment: In theory what you did should work. But if your practice is different, something must have gone wrong. Not enough details in your post to help debug though. Can you share a couple of screenshots? Did the user accept the invite? Are branch protections in place? Did the user generate a PAT token with only read permissions?

Comment: Hi, this is a private repo, so I can't share screenshots. The user is an organization member and accepted the invite (through you should be able to add outside collaborators and give them write access). There are no branch protections, I don't think he has generated tokens.

Comment: Then, with the info you provided, he should have access.

Comment: I know, but he doesn't. This does work on another repo, but for this one I ended up having to give him admin access.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, when the private repo is yours and someone else opens a pull request to it, you as the owner have to merge the pull request in the respective branch.